# Javascript appendChild() call not working in IE

Tags: javascript, dom

Could someone explain why this piece of script won't work in IE? It seems to work alright in Firefox.
I'm new with the appendChild() API.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function makeTable()
{
   nTable=document.createElement('table');
   nTable.setAttribute('id','myTable');
   nTable.setAttribute('border','1');

   nRow1=document.createElement('tr');
   nData11=document.createElement('td');
   nData11.setAttribute('colspan','2');
   nCenter11=document.createElement('center');
   nBold=document.createElement('b');
   nBold.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Title'));
   nCenter11.appendChild(nBold);
   nData11.appendChild(nCenter11);
   nRow1.appendChild(nData11);

   nRow2=document.createElement('tr');
   nData21=document.createElement('td');
   nCenter21=document.createElement('center');
  nCenter21.appendChild(document.createTextNode('21'));
  nData21.appendChild(nCenter21);
  nData22=document.createElement('td');
   nCenter22=document.createElement('center');
  nCenter22.appendChild(document.createTextNode('22'));
  nData22.appendChild(nCenter22);
  nRow2.appendChild(nData21);
  nRow2.appendChild(nData22);

  nTable.appendChild(nRow1);
  nTable.appendChild(nRow2);

  alert('Almost there !');
  try
  {
   document.getElementById('container').appendChild(nTable);
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    alert(e.message);
  }
   return;

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
</div>
<input type=button value='Go' onclick='makeTable();'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: bah. Probably IE needs a `<tbody>` as the parent of the rows. It's a bit of a whiner like that.

Answer (score 4):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532998(VS.85).aspx#TOM_DOM.  Similarly to what Crescent Fresh mentioned in his comment, IE needs a tbody element inserted into the table so that you can use the DOM:

> **Note**  Internet Explorer requires that
>   you create a **tBody** element and insert
>   it into the **table** when using the DOM.
>   Since you are manipulating the
>   document tree directly, Internet
>   Explorer does not create the **tBody**,
>   which is automatically implied when
>   using HTML.